# WRL and VRML to Matplotlib/Numpy

Tags: python, visualization, numpy, scipy, plotting

I would like to import (or parse ??) a [WRL/VRML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML) file format in python in order to work the data with Matplotlib. Is there any way of converting this file format into plottable numpy arrays ?

I attached a photo a WRL file visualized with the [FreeWRL](http://freewrl.sourceforge.net/) viewer
[image]

Comment: I am not really sure if this question is more suitable for http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'd try looking at PyVRML or ScientificPython to start.

Comment: I stumbled on it while searching but I couldnt find a decent documentation not to mention that the Github repository links are broken !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{Assuming you still need the code} Let A1.wrl is your wrl file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import re
holder = []
with open("A1.wrl", "rb") as vrml:
    for lines in vrml:
        a = re.findall("[-0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{6}", lines)
        if len(a) == 3:
            holder.append(map(float, a))

holder_array = np.array(holder) #if you want numpy array

#3D Plotting
x,y,z = zip(*holder)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

My A.wrl: http://pastebin.com/PeVXbR5C

File generate:

[image]

Comment: what version of `wrl` files are you using ? I tested it but no regular expression are found, and the numpy array are empty.

Comment: @SAAD: #VRML V2.0 utf8

Comment: your `A.wrl` file works, but I think your python script doesnt work with my file `B.wrl` (http://pastebin.com/HCVjqETa)

Comment: @SAAD: My code is just an example. You can just change the regex according to what you want to get and it will do it. In your files there are more than one place to get the coordinates and the numbers are in 2E-01 format, your code have to just catch that.

Comment: Actually i am very familiarbwith `re` module, nonethless i ll take a look at yourr wrl file to see how you did it. For this, you have also my up vote also.